# Why does a system call from Ruby to bash claim to be from zsh?

Tags: ruby, bash, zsh

When I execute

```
system "bash -c 'echo $SHELL'"
```

I get the response

```
/bin/zsh
```

How could this be? I do get `bash`, however, as expected, when I execute

system "bash -c 'echo $0'"

I'm on OS X (not that that's likely to matter) Mavericks, and my default shell is zsh, but since [Ruby supposedly uses the Bourne shell for all its `system` calls](http://greyblake.com/blog/2013/09/21/how-to-call-bash-not-shell-from-ruby/) I wouldn't expect my default shell to make any difference.

Answer (score 4):

`$SHELL` is not the current shell. It is the parent shell of your session, which is normally the shell that is configured in `/etc/passwd`. It will not suddenly change if you spawn another subshell.

EDIT: Also, if you separate the arguments in the `system` call, Ruby will not invoke a shell. Thus, `system "bash -c 'echo $SHELL'"` looks like this:

```
zsh -> ruby -> sh -> bash
```

But `system "/bin/bash", "-c", "echo $SHELL"` only invokes a shell once:

```
zsh -> ruby -> bash
```

So, Ruby does not always use Bourne shell; but rather, *if* it needs to use a shell, it will use `sh`.

Comment: @rici: You are correct, of course; it should be `sh`. But in most modern systems `sh` is actually `bash` in disguise, makes my thinking sloppy. I'll edit and fix, thank you.